# PCM Audio mixing which is having two different sample rates is not working

Tags: android, audio-processing, sample-rate, superpowered

I have two audio files both are having different sample rates. I am converting both audios into PCM audios and then mixing them. So in the final output, one audio is going faster than the actual one. I have used the [Superpowered](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-iOS-Linux-Windows-tvOS-macOS-Interactive-Audio-Platform) SDK for audio mixing and decoding. Can anyone help me to achieve the actual result?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You would have to resample one so they are both the same sample rate.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure where to specify the rate change after resampling and how to use it in decoding.

Comment: Did you find the solution Bro, because I am facing a problem similar to yours ?

Comment: I have used FFMPEG to resample audio, I haven't got any solution in superpowered resampling @Sy4tech.